# Two tables using one entity

Tags: android, sql, database

My question relates about Room and tables. 
I have one POJO called `movie`, this POJO holds a `title`, `image`, `overview`, `releaseDate`  and `rating`.

`movie` is typed as an `@Entity(tableName = movie_table)`, this table holds the most popular movies queried by an http call which is: `/movie/popular` endpoint, I'm asked to use a filter button which switch from most popular to top rated movies, the second filter uses another http call which is: `/movie/top_rated` endpoint. Based on that I need to different tables, maybe one called: `most_popular_movies` and another called `top_rated_movies`. How can I achieve that using just one entity? Do I need to duplicate the `movie` POJO? or is there another way to achieve this filtering using those two different http calls?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you add two additional fields to the existing object, is_top_rated (true/false) and is_popular (true/false)? You'd have to keep those up-to-date by updating the object periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create multiple tables. You could add two more columns to the table, i.e. `rank_most_popular` and `rank_top_rated`. Then when you fetch most popular movies, you'll insert them into the database with a ranking that you assign them. Then, when you would fetch top rated movies, you'd just insert new movies into the database and update existing ones with assigned top rated rankings. You can then write queries to filter the ones you need. Something along these lines.

Entity class

```
@Entity(tableName = "movie_table")
public class MovieEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private int topRatedRank;
    private int mostPopularRank;

    // Other fields...

}
```

Dao class

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(MovieEntity movie);

    @Update
    int update(MovieEntity entity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE mostPopularRank <> -1 ORDER BY mostPopularRank ASC LIMIT :count")
    List<MovieEntity> getMostPopular(int count);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE topRatedRank <> -1 ORDER BY topRatedRank ASC LIMIT :count")
    List<MovieEntity> getTopRated(int count);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM movie_table WHERE :id = id")
    MovieEntity getById(long id);

}
```

And when you receive movies you just assign a rank to each movie (similar for top rated)

```
public void mostPopularReceived(List<MovieEntity> mostPopular) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mostPopular.size(); i++) {
        MovieEntity movie = mostPopular.get(i);
        MovieEntity dbMovie = movieDao.getById(movie.getId());
        if (dbMovie == null) {
            movie.setMostPopularRank(i);
            movieDao.insert(movie);
        } else {
            dbMovie.setMostPopularRank(i);
            movieDao.update(dbMovie);
        }
    }
}
```